# Прошу помочь сделать SQL запрос: вывести 22 записи из базы по моим

Tags: запрос, mysql

У меня задача:

Есть таблица БД `t_table` там марки и модели авто.

На данный момент есть 2 вкладки где из таблицы  `t_table` выводятся  все марки авто (т.е. полный список 100 моделей).

Я хочу разделить, чтобы:

1. в одной вкладке выводились все марки авто (т.е. полный список 100 моделей)-- на данный момент выводятся,
2. во второй вкладке выводился урезанный список, т.е. только те модели что мне нужно скажем 22 моделей.

Нужно правильно написать `SQL` запросы на вывод этих 22 моделей!
INSERT INTO t_models (id, alias, parent_id, name, logo, descr, status) VALUES (119, 'ac-cars', 0, 'AC Cars', 'ac-cars.gif', NULL, 1),

P/S создание 2-ой таблицы трудоемко поскольку много кода перелопатить придется.

Прошу помочь уважаемых гуру. Фри-ланс отказался т.к слишком сложно...там 5 файлов которые нужно посмотреть и поправить. Если нужно скину по почте...

Comment: и по какому признаку определять, какие именно 22 модели вам нужны?

Comment: INSERT INTO `t_models` (`id`, `alias`, `parent_id`, `name`, `logo`, `descr`, `status`) VALUES 
(119, 'ac-cars', 0, 'AC Cars', 'ac-cars.gif', NULL, 1), 

По по выбранным мной id

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM t_table LIMIT 22
```

Comment: что спросили то и получили )))

Comment: Извините файлы http://zalil.ru/34410688

Comment: и что в файлах?

Comment: то что хотелось бы сделать...